# Get CompanyName for group user using Azure GraphAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using GraphAPI from Azure and want to GET data from the API using the graphClient SDK. I want to list all members of a specific group and display some more details about them. The problem is that I miss the property CompanyName in the response from the API (null).

I build the request like this (searchParam is the group id):

```
await graphClient.Groups[searchParam.ToString()]
                                        .Members
                                        .Request()
                                        .GetAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Anyone know if I can get the CompanyName in the same request? (I dont want to make another request just to fetch the companyname).

I tried filter and extend methods, but not sure if that is the way to go?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions as outlined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)?

Comment: yes premission was right, I had to work some more with the select feature. As in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code pls and it worked for me.

```
var members = await graphClient.Groups["{group_id}"].Members.Request().Select("id,displayName,companyName").GetAsync();
```

[image]

This is because, when we call list member graph api, it will return a list of  `directoryObject` objects, and user is also a kind of `directoryObject`. And when [`user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) is the response, it won't return `companyName` by default, so we need to use Odata `select` feature.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i was searching for! Thank you! :)